# Clarification Needed: Points Rummy Doubt on TajRummy Platform

Tags: rummy

I've been enjoying playing Points Rummy on the [TajRummy platform](https://www.tajrummy.com/), but I've encountered a situation that has left me a bit confused. I'm hoping some of you experienced players can offer some clarity.

In a recent game, I found myself in a position where I had completed all the necessary sequences and sets required for a valid declaration. However, I was unsure about the scoring and penalty system in a specific scenario.

Here's the situation: I had melded all my 13 cards into valid sequences and sets, including at least one pure sequence and two or more sequences overall. However, I noticed that one of my sets included more than four cards, and I had used jokers to complete it.

My question is, does having a set with more than four cards impact my score or penalty in any way? Specifically, does using jokers to create a set with more than four cards affect the calculation of points for my hand?

I've reviewed the rules provided by Taj Rummy, but I couldn't find a clear answer to this specific scenario. I want to ensure that I understand the scoring system correctly to avoid any confusion during future games.

I appreciate any insights or explanations you can provide on this matter.

Comment: Did it affect your score in that game? If so, how, exactly? Please provide complete details. (But of course the best option is to contact Taj Rummy's support directly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, using jokers to create a set with more than four cards do not affect the score.**
Points Rummy is a single round Indian Rummy with a Rupee-value for each point.  The rules of [TajRummy:Points Rummy](https://www.tajrummy.com/rummy-variations/points-rummy/) is identical to the rules of [Pagat:Indian Rummy](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/indian.html#:%7E:text=The%20objective%20is%20to%20form,%2D9%2D10%2DJ%2DQ%2DK%2DA.).

> Once you have melded all 13 cards into valid sequences and sets, you
> may declare for the win. To Declare successfully, you must fulfil the
> following conditions:
>
> - You Must have at least 2 valid sequences
> - You must have at least 1 valid Pure Sequence
> - All cards have been melded.

Calculation of winnings at TajRummy:

> Winnings = (Sum of all points that opponents receive) X (Rupee value of the point) - (Taj Rummy platform fees)